# Selecting sub queries using all operator without joining in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, operators, mariadb

I need to display the ID, Name and Date of birth from all workers from department 1 who are younger than workers from department 2. I'm trying to do with *without* a join.

Here's what I have at the minute, it doesn't fail when I run it but it shows all the workers from department 2, regardless of their birthday.

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT(fName," " ,lName) AS "Worker Name", dob
FROM Worker
WHERE dob <= ALL (SELECT department
FROM Worker
WHERE deparment = 1 
)
AND deparment = 2;
```

Comment: You're comparing `dob` with `department`. Try `<= all (select dob`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want check for dob then you should select dob

```
  SELECT ID, CONCAT(fName," " ,lName) AS "Worker Name", dob
  FROM Worker
  WHERE dob <= ALL (SELECT dob
  FROM Worker
  WHERE deparment = 1 
  )
  AND deparment = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should list all workers from department1 that are younger from workers in department 2:

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT(fName," " ,lName) AS "Worker Name", dob
FROM Worker
WHERE dob <  (SELECT min(w2.dob)
FROM Worker w2
WHERE w2.deparment = 2
)
AND deparment = 1
```